# SpriteKit - Wrong contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My Hero / Player instance can get destroyed by either touching an enemy instance or a enemyBullet instance. This is my enemy:

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy
physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet
physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
physicsBody?.dynamic = true
```

This is my enemyBullet:

```
bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.size)
bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemyBullet
bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hero
bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
```

And this is my hero:

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hero
physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy | PhysicsCategory.enemyBullet
physicsBody?.dynamic = false
```

My Player does properly contact with enemy instances, but does not contact with enemyBullets. Instead, there is a random SKPhysicsContact instantiated, when a enemy shoots. This is what my handling function looks like:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        // Enemy + bullet
        if((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet) || (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy)) {
            // TODO
        }

        // Hero + enemy
        else if((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) || (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero)) {
            print("HERO AND ENEMY")
        }

        // Hero + enemyBullet
        else if((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemyBullet) || (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemyBullet && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero)) {
            print("HERO AND BULLET")
        }
        else {
            print("DEBUG: \(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask) AND ˜\(contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)")
        }
    }
```

So: What happens is that whenever an enemy shoots (shooting enemyBullet), it will run to the else in my handling function. This will print "DEBUG: 1 AND 6". 1 = enemy, 6 = enemyBullet.

Why should my enemy throw a contact when he shoots the bullet? How can i make my game detect when the hero is hit by enemyBullet?

EDIT: Thanks to @KnightOfDragon:

1. When using the ContactBitMask and CategoryBitMask make sure to not simply set them to 1,2,3,4,etc. Set them to:

   static let environment: UInt32         = 0b00000000000000000000000000000001
   static let powerup: UInt32             = 0b00000000000000000000000000000010
   static let hero: UInt32                = 0b00000000000000000000000000100000
   static let bullet: UInt32              = 0b00000000000000000000000001000000
   static let enemy: UInt32               = 0b00000000000000000100000000000000
   static let enemyBullet: UInt32         = 0b00000000000000001000000000000000

   static let enemyAndEnemyBullet: UInt32 = 0b00000000000000001100000000000000
2. For the love of god: When using sprites where you expect contacts from aka SKPhysicsContact, always set them to `dynamic = true`. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 6,  then you are not using masks correctly.  Mask values have to be represented in a power of 2, so that no bits overlay each other.  By saying 6,  you are saying 0110, so your enemy bullet can contact whatever 2 and 4 represent.  Post your category enum so that I may complete this answer.

Edit

```
static let enemy: UInt32       = 0b00000000000000000000000000000001 
static let bullet: UInt32      = 0b00000000000000000000000000000010 
static let hero: UInt32        = 0b00000000000000000000000000000100 
static let environment: UInt32 = 0b00000000000000000000000000001000 
static let powerup: UInt32     = 0b00000000000000000000000000010000
static let enemyBullet: UInt32 = 0b00000000000000000000000000100000
```

Then, to make your code more readable,  you can do things like

```
static let enemyAndEnemyBullet: UInt32 = 0b00000000000000000000000000100001
...
player.contactBitMask =  enemyAndEnemyBullet;
...

if((bodyA == player.categoryBitMask) && (bodyB.categoryBitMask | enemyAndEnemyBullet) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

instead of using

```
player.contactBitMask =  enemy | enemyBullet;
...
if((bodyA == player.categoryBitMask) && (bodyB.categoryBitMask == enemy || bodyB == enemyBullet))
{
    ...
}
```

Now all the leading zeros are not needed,  I did it this way so you can see how the mask works and what the max is. (32 different masks)

Comment: static let enemy: UInt32 = 1
    static let bullet: UInt32 = 2
    static let hero: UInt32 = 3
    static let environment: UInt32 = 4
    static let powerup: UInt32 = 5
    static let enemyBullet: UInt32 = 6

Didn't know that. So i am supposed to do 1,2,4,8,16?

Comment: @KnightOfDragon: Well thanks a lot for your answer. I adapted my code into not using 1,2,3,4,etc. for my enum anymore. Still i am getting no contact for hero + enemyBullets. This time, there is no SKPhysicsContact at all thrown. (I have not edited anything else other than the enum!)

Comment: you may have to post more,  are you saying no contact at all, or just no contact that falls into hero and bullet

Comment: also, you are throwing me off,  you said enum,  but had me post constants... which is it?

Comment: @KnightOfDragon: Sorry, i used wrong names. This is the complete code that belongs to my problem: http://pastebin.com/Tfs1SZbS. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you didn't follow direction `contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemyAndEnemyBullet` means that you need to collide with both enemy and bullet at the same time,  you need `contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.hero && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask | PhysicsCategory.enemyAndEnemyBullet) > 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99064/discussion-between-boa456-and-knight0fdragon).